# Should I use Mann Whitney U or Wilcoxon Rank for Feature Selection Effect?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, feature-selection, nonparametric

I implemented an application to see how 9 different algorithms are affected by the feature selection in a dataset. As a result, I have accuracy values obtained before and after feature selection for each algorithm. I want to measure whether this feature selection method changes/affects the accuracy value in each algorithm. Therefore, should I use the Mann-Whitney U test or the Wilcoxon Rank Test to see this effect?

PS: I know, it can be seen that the feature selection has an effect on accuracy, but I want to test this situation scientifically.

[image: These are the results.]

Comment: You have paired data (two 'accuracy' values for each 'algorithm'). A Mann-Whitney U test is equivalent to a Wilcoxon Rank Sum tests. A nonparametric test for paired data is the Wilcoxon Signed-Rank test, which looks at one sample consisting of the paired differences. In R, syntax for your data (with appropriate variable names) would be `wilcox.test(Orig, Select, pair=T)` or `wilcox.test(Orig - Select)`.

Comment: Thank you very much!